# render typescript map in react jsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary, jsx

I have map object :

```
const myMap = new Map<number,string>([
   [10, "text1"],
   [15, "text2"],
   [20, "text3"]
])
```

Looking for ways how to iterate over this map in React JSX .
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
let nodes: React.ReactNode[] = [];
myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    nodes.push(<your jsx>);
})
return nodes; // if you are in a component where you want to render
```

Or if you want to go a bit deeper, you can [augment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) the Map type to add a map function.

```
declare global {
    interface Map<K, V> {
        map<K, V, R>(
            this: Map<K, V>,
            callbackfn: (value: V, key: K, map: globalThis.Map<K, V>) => R,
            thisArg?: any,
        ): R[];
    }
}

Map.prototype.map = function <K, V, R>(
    this: Map<K, V>,
    callbackfn: (value: V, key: K, map: globalThis.Map<K, V>) => R,
    thisArg?: any,
): R[] {
    const arr: R[] = [];
    this.forEach((value, key, map) => {
        arr.push(callbackfn(value, key, map));
    });

    return arr;
};

const nodes = myMap.map((value, key) => <div>...</div>);
```